# Stop fluent from generating double foreign keys

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

When I generate my database from fluent one of my tables as 2 of every field and I can't figure out why

like I have the fk keys how I want them too look(StudentId) but it also generates the keys how they want it to look(student_id)

```
   public class PermissionLevel
    {
        public virtual int PermissionLevelId { get; private set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
    }

  public class PermissionMap : ClassMap<Permission>
    {
        public PermissionMap()
        {
            Table("Permissions");
            Id(x => x.PermissionId).Column("PermissionId");
            Map(x => x.Name).NvarcharWithMaxSize().Not.Nullable();
            HasMany(x => x.PermissionLevels);
        }
    }


public class PermissionLevelMap : ClassMap<PermissionLevel>
{
    public PermissionLevelMap()
    {
        Table("PermissionLevels");
        Id(x => x.PermissionLevelId).Column("PermissionLevelId");
        References(x => x.Permission).Not.Nullable().Column("PermissionId");
        References(x => x.Student).Not.Nullable().Column("StudentId");
        References(x => x.Course).Not.Nullable().Column("CourseId");

    }
}

  public class StudentMap : ClassMap<Student>
    {
        public StudentMap()
        {
            Table("Students");
            Id(x => x.StudentId).Column("StudentId");
            HasMany(x => x.PermissionLevels);
        }
    }
```

all mine look like that and I get

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/b20cd95baa4cde6d8b06c98d50b8ddec.png))</sub>

```
ISessionFactory fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure()
                                                  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Connection")))
                                                  .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Framework.Data.Mapping.StudentMap>())
                                                  .ExposeConfiguration(BuidSchema)
                                                  .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration code? As well as the mapping for PermissionLevel?

Comment: @mannish - oops posted the wrong one meant to do PermissionLevel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to duplicate the issue, but try this: in your configuration, change the mappings to include a convention for the foreign key names like:

```
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Framework.Data.Mapping.StudentMap>().Conventions.Add(ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id"))
```

With that in place, you can remove the Column() call from the individual mapping files and achieve the same result.  Since I can't reproduce your exact issue, I'm hoping this will also clear up the problem (I have a hunch that Fluent's AutoMap feature is getting in the mix somehow but it doesn't look like your code is allowing for this, so it really is just a hunch).

Comment: Just to confirm, I just ran this code against my own solution and it worked as expected, no dupes, and created FKs with the convention "ReferenceEntityId". Hope it helps. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: that seems to have done it. I figured out why it was making the duplicates. I don't think it liked when I put a column() on a reference. But if I did not have that their then I only got the underscore ones what I did not want. Now the db it generates looks pretty much the same(expect that it does not draw a relationship to a one to one in ms sql designer) as my db I created.